# Markov Chain: SQL Database and Java Representation

Tags: java, database, data-structures, text, markov-chains

Now this question is a bit obscure. I have a text-based markov chain that I've generated by parsing user-typed text. It is used to generate an almost-coherent string of gibberish and works by storing the probability of a given word being the next word in a text sequence, based on the current word in the sequence. In javascript, this object would look something like the following:

```
var text_markov_chain = {
    "apple" : {
        "cake" : 0.2,
        "sauce" : 0.8
    },
    "transformer" : {
        "movie" : 0.95,
        "cat" : 0.025,
        "dog" : 0.025
    }
    "cat" : {
        "dog : 0.5,
        "nap" : 0.5
    }
    // ...
}
```

So, for example, if the current word is transformer, then the next word we generate will have a 95% chance of being movie, and a 2.5% chance of being cat or dog respectively.

My question is twofold:

- What is the best way of representing this object in Java? Best as in I care 50% about fast access and 50% about memory usage
- How would I store this object in a single database table (for example MySQL)?

**Update: In response to @biziclop's answer, and @SanjayTSharma's comment, below my class I ended up writing (it's a work in progress, MIT license. It currently only generates first-order Markov Chains.**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MarkovChain {
    HashMap<String, TreeMap<String, Float>> chain;
    Set<String> known_words;
    Random rand;

    /**
     * Generates a first order Markov Chain from the given text
     * @param input_text The text to parse
     */
    public MarkovChain(String input_text) {
        init(input_text, 1);
    }

    /**
     * Generates a nth order Markov Chain from the given text
     * @param input_text The text to parse
     * @param n The order of the Markov Chain
     */
    public MarkovChain(String input_text, int n) {
        init(input_text, n);
    }

    /**
     * Reads a Markov Chain from the given input stream. The object is assumed
     * to be binary and serialized
     * @param in The input stream, eg from a network port or file
     */
    public MarkovChain(InputStream in) {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream ob_in = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            chain = (HashMap<String, TreeMap<String, Float>>)ob_in.readObject();
            known_words = chain.keySet();
            ob_in.close();
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            chain = null;
            known_words = null;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            chain = null;
            known_words = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the next word, according to the Markov Chain probabilities 
     * @param current_word The current generated word
     */
    public String nextWord(String current_word) {
        if(current_word == null) return nextWord();

        // Then head off down the yellow-markov-brick-road
        TreeMap<String, Float> wordmap = chain.get(current_word);
        if(wordmap == null) {
            /* This *shouldn't* happen, but if we get a word that isn't in the
             * Markov Chain, choose another random one
             */
            return nextWord();
        }

        // Choose the next word based on an RV (Random Variable)
        float rv = rand.nextFloat();
        for(String word : wordmap.keySet()) {
            float prob = wordmap.get(word);
            rv -= prob;
            if(rv <= 0) {
                return word;
            }
        }

        /* We should never get here - if we do, then the probabilities have
         * been calculated incorrectly in the Markov Chain
         */
        assert false : "Probabilities in Markov Chain must sum to one!";
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the next word when the current word is unknown, irrelevant or
     * non existant (at the start of the sequence - randomly picks from known_words
     */
    public String nextWord() {
        return (String) known_words.toArray()[rand.nextInt(known_words.size())];
    }

    private void init(String input_text, int n) {
        if(input_text.length() <= 0) return;
        if(n <= 0) return;

        chain = new HashMap<String, TreeMap<String, Float>>();
        known_words = new HashSet<String>();
        rand = new Random(new Date().getTime());

        /** Generate the Markov Chain! **/
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input_text);

        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String word = st.nextToken();
            TreeMap<String, Float> wordmap = new TreeMap<String, Float>();

            // First check if the current word has previously been parsed
            if(known_words.contains(word)) continue;
            known_words.add(word);

            // Build the Markov probability table for this word
            StringTokenizer st_this_word = new StringTokenizer(input_text);
            String previous = "";
            while (st_this_word.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String next_word = st_this_word.nextToken();

                if(previous.equals(word)) {
                    if(wordmap.containsKey(next_word)) {
                        // Increment the number of counts for this word by 1
                        float num = wordmap.get(next_word);
                        wordmap.put(next_word, num + 1);
                    } else {
                        wordmap.put(next_word, 1.0f);
                    }
                }

                previous = next_word;
            } // End while (st_this_word.hasMoreTokens())

            /* The wordmap now contains a map of words and the number of occurrences they have.
             * We need to convert this to the probability of getting that word by dividing
             * by the total number of words there were
             */
            int total_number_of_words = wordmap.values().size();
            for(String k : wordmap.keySet()) {
                int num_occurances = wordmap.get(k).intValue();
                wordmap.put(k, 1.0f*num_occurances/total_number_of_words);
            }

            // Finally, we are ready to add this word and wordmap to the Markov chain
            chain.put(word, wordmap);

        } // End while (st.hasMoreTokens())

        // The (first order) Markov Chain has now been built!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By storing it in Java, I'm guessing you think about storing it in a way that's easy to generate a sequence from.

First you need a hashmap, with the words being the keys. The values of this hashmap will be a treemap with the keys being the cumulative probability and the value being the next word.

So it will be something like:

```
    HashMap<String, TreeMap<Double, String>> words = new HashMap<String, TreeMap<Double,String>>();

    TreeMap<Double, String> appleMap = new TreeMap<Double, String>();
    appleMap.put( 0.2d, "cake");
    appleMap.put( 1.0d, "sauce");
    words.put( "apple", appleMap );

    TreeMap<Double, String> transformerMap = new TreeMap<Double, String>();
    transformerMap.put( 0.95d, "movie");
    transformerMap.put( 0.975d, "cat");
    transformerMap.put( 1.0d, "dog");
    words.put( "transformer", transformerMap );
```

It's very easy to generate the next word from this structure.

```
private String generateNextWord( HashMap<String, TreeMap<Double, String>> words, String currentWord ) {
    TreeMap<Double, String> probMap = words.get( currentWord );
    double d = Math.random();
    return probMap.ceilingEntry( d ).getValue();
}
```

In a relational database you can simply have a single table with three columns: current word, next word and weight. So you're basically storing the edges of the state transition graph of your Markov chain

You could also normalize it into two tables: a vertex table to store the words against word ids, and an edge table storing current word id, next word id and weight, but unless you want to store extra fields with your words, I don't think this is necessary.

Comment: I'd recommend hiding this behind a sane class to avoid going through the motions of dealing with a Map every time the client code needs to access the Markov chain.

Comment: Also, that `d` prefix can be removed since floating point literals in Java are by default `double`.

Comment: @Sanjay T. Sharma Well, normally you'd parse the data from a file anyway, I just put the init code in to convey the idea. I personally prefer to use the "d" or "f" suffix at all times.

Comment: I know; my comments are meant to add additional context to your post. No nitpick intended. :-)

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer to include the bit about databases @bizclop! Exactly what I was after.