# PostgreSQL database with a variable number of values

Tags: database, postgresql, data-structures

I want to make a postgres database that has unique `TEXT` keys and a variable number of `TEXT` and `DECIMAL` pairs, similar to the Javascript representation [in this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6610058)

> [...] In javascript, this object would look something like the following:
>
> ```
> var text_markov_chain = {
>     "apple" : {
>         "cake" : 0.2,
>         "sauce" : 0.8
>     },
>     "transformer" : {
>         "movie" : 0.95,
>         "cat" : 0.025,
>         "dog" : 0.025
>     }
>     "cat" : {
>         "dog : 0.5,
>         "nap" : 0.5
>     }
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> [...]

What would intuitively make the most sense is to have a separate table for each unique `TEXT` key value in the main table, but I don't think this kind of functionality is normal in postgres. How should I be approaching this?

Comment: KEy value pair? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/hstore.html or http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-hstore/?

Comment: Attribute, Product, Product_Attributes. Product_Attribute_values.  Attributes such as {cake sause housing attribute ID, name, datatype} products such as (apple transformer cat) product_Attributes such as {Apple cake, Apple Sauce} and finally Product_Attribute_values {apple, cake, .02}  this way you can specify what attributes are allowed for each product, and then for each product what the value is for the allowed attributes.  you could have a "Version" record as well if history matters

Comment: @xQbert the hstore variable type seems perfect. Is there any reason I wouldn't want to use it?

Comment: Aside from it NOT being a good design choice in a relational database; no.  If your intent with this information is a document store (insert/read display w/o aggregation/analysis/filtering) or if you have a very dynamic model, it's a reasonable choice. It's not a good choice if if you need to do any type of data analysis/filtering/sorting as the data is unstructured. a different stack site Q&A offers some further insight https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115825/jsonb-with-indexing-vs-hstore  My second comment shows how to model this in a relational way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this work for you, because you will have to create a parser to switch between object and db. But you need something like

**Yourtable:**

```
object_name, parameter_name, value
```

So you will have:

```
 apple, cake, 0.2
 apple, sauce, 0.8
 transformer, movie, 0.95
 transformer, cat, 0.025
 transformer, dog, 0.025
 cat, dog, 0.5
 cat, nap, 0.5
```